# How do I fix the compression fitting connection on my refrigerator water line?

Tags: refrigerator

in replacing a broken water line from the water valve to the filter the old damaged line got stuck inside the compression fitting.  After I dug it out, the compression fitting will no long hold the plastic tubing.  other than replacing the entire water valve is there a way to fix this.  Sounds crazy but could I put glue on the tubing and then insert it in the compression fitting.  Please give me an easy solution, I am a elderly woman who does her own home repairs.

Comment: Are you sure the compression fitting is assembled correctly? Is it tight enough? (Don't wrench on the nipple without supporting it.)

Comment: If it's the 1/4" compression fitting with a brass ring that slides down over then end of the tube, then you just need a new brass ring.  They get bent when you tighten the nut, that's why you had to dig the old one out.  They are sold separately.

Comment: I wonder if there isn't a misunderstanding about how compression fittings work (and was the brass ring even reinstalled?).

Comment: [This is the brass ring](http://imgur.com/Sm82JxA) that I was referring.  It gets compressed when the nut is tightened making it pretty much a single use item.

Comment: I thought the ring was called a ferrule. I agree once compressed they are done and need to be replaced. the can be made out of plastic also much easier to damage.

Comment: When used with some size plastic lines they have an insert tube that goes inside the plastic line to strengthen it enough for the compression to work, (besides the nut and ferrule)

Comment: @Tyson How exactly do you "dig" the old one out?  It seems so joined to the copper that it might as well be soldered on!

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQGL8MBLlaE) shows basic assembly of small compression fittings. The only things I would add:

- the ferrule (whether plastic or brass) is indeed a "single use" item, as mentioned by @Tyson and @Ed Beal
- you can use a brass ferrule on plastic tubing, but not a plastic ferrule on copper tubing
- the video says to tighten a single turn past hand tight. I say tighten well, regardless of turns needed; you need to actually squeeze that ferrule onto the tubing.